# Integration testing in grails using netbeans

Tags: grails, integration-testing

I am using netbeans as the ide to develop grails web applications and am facing problems in integration testing.i created an integration test for a domain class ProgressData as ProgressDataIntegration in netbeans and it generated a code full of errors

```
package main
import static org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.*

class ProgressDataIntegrationTests{

@Before
void setUp() {
    // Setup logic here
}

@After
void tearDown() {
    // Tear down logic here
}

@Test
void testSomething() {
    fail "Implement me"
}
}
```

need help on how to remove these errors

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you [create a grails domain class](http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Command%20Line/create-domain-class.html) an integration test will also be created for you containing the code you posted.  By default the test fails, as a prompt to write some tests for your new domain class, i.e. The line:

```
fail "Implement me"
```

If you remove this line your test will pass, but it also fails to actually test anything.